# JS - Rock, Paper, Scissor, buttons instead of Prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code for a basic "rock, paper, scissor" game in JS. It works with a promt but I would like to be able to make your choices with buttons. I would like to use "getElementById" and "addEventListener("click")". Could anyone point me in the right direction?

HTML:

```
  <button id ="rock"> Rock </button>
```

Paper 
   Scissor

JavaScript:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");



var computerChoice = Math.random();
 if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";

} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";

} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
 } console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);


var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
 if (choice1 === choice2) {
  return "The result is a tie!";
  } 

  else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return "rock wins";
  }
   else {
      return "paper wins";


  } if (choice1 === "paper") {
   if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    }
     else {
        return "scissors wins";


    } if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins";

        } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
        }
        }
      }
  } 
   compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onclick` event handler ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)) in several blocks like this:

```
document.getElementById('rock').onclick = function(e){
  userChoice = 'rock'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (click "run code snippet"):

```js
document.getElementById('rock').onclick = user;
document.getElementById('paper').onclick = user;
document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = user;


function user(){
    var userChoice = this.id;
    console.log("User: " + userChoice)

    var computerChoice = Math.random();
         if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
             computerChoice = "rock";
          }else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
             computerChoice = "paper";
          }else{
             computerChoice = "scissors";
          }; 

    console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

    console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice)); 

    function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    
      if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";
        }
 
        if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "rock wins";
            }else{
                return "paper wins";
            }
    }
 
         if (choice1 === "paper") {
             if (choice2 === "rock") {
                 return "paper wins";
              } else {
                  return "scissors wins";
              }
       }
  
       if (choice1 === "scissors") {
             if (choice2 === "rock") {
                 return "rock wins";
             } else {
                 return "scissors wins";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors">Scissor</button>
```

PS: your function `compare` was returning `undefined` for some cases.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out, can I ask, how would you represent the ouput on the HTML instead of the console?